# Carousell, how to show picture 1 without clicking one ahead or behind?

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I am quite new to coding from scratch, but I am trying to build a very very simple website. And I wanted an image carousel at the start. I already have it coded // I copied some code from a tutorial.

My problem is that, when I open my websites front page the first image doesn't load in, until I either click forwards or backwards. And I want it to load image 1 as soon as the website loads in. Can anyone help me with that?

**index.html**

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Text1Here</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Text2Here</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/image3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Text3Here</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: There's not enough info, but I'm guessing that JS is run before layout is rendered or the initial value of slideIndex isn't what you expect it to be (maybe `undefined`). Most likely the second case.

Comment: Does your console (F12) show any erros? slideIndex is not defined in your example code.

Comment: Yes my console shows an error in the script.js file - However I read the error to have something to do with the changeing slides buttons.


script.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
    at showSlides (script.js:26:24)
    at script.js:2:1
showSlides @ script.js:26
(anonymous) @ script.js:2

Comment: I created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1xqser6w/ I can't see the images of course, but in the developer console you can see, that all images try to load. The first slide is also shown. What is the problem? Maybe other scripts on the page?

Comment: The problem was that the first image in the carousel wasn't being loaded when the index.html was run. However after looking at what Christian said in the first comment I moved my js loader to the bottom of my html and now it all loads like it should do. So now problem anymore.

Comment: Okay, but you should maybe remove the dots handling, because that created some error output to the console. The corrected code is on the bottom of my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to copy the "dots"-elements from the tutorial. If you get errors in your console, this could be the reason, why it aborts further execution.

Try to change your HTML as follows:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Text1Here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/image2.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Text2Here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/image3.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Text3Here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
  <div class="dots"></div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

I added the three "dots"-elements. If you don't want them, you can remove them from the HTML, but you have to remove every JS code that works with the dots variable.

Here is the JS code without the dots handlings:

```
function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```